# Why I see only the publish web template when I click on new site?

Tags: publishing-site, web-template

I have a sharepoint 2010 portal. The site collection is from the site template "publishing site". When I would like to create a subsite I see the popup with the web templates. I see only 1 template with the name "Publishing Site".

Why I dont see other webtemplates which are OOTB from SharePoint?

What do I need to do to see more web OOTB templates?

See here what I see in the new site popup:

[image: New Site Popup to select web template]

Answer (score 1):

In the site collection, click **Site Actions > Site Settings > Page Layout and Site Templates** (under **Look and Feel**). Here you can specify which templates can be used for sub sites and which page layouts can be used for publishing pages on the current site.

Comment: I dont see page layout and site templates under look and feel, what to do? Is it some feature which I need to activate/deactivate?

Comment: What are your access privileges? I believe you must be site collection admin to change the setting at the site collection level.